# Is there a way to syndicate content from PeopleSoft HRMS application?

Tags: php, xml, peoplesoft

I am looking for a way to pull in data from our PeopleSoft HRMS application without using ODBC. Preferably, would like to find away to either grab all open listings in either XML, RSS, or other type of general format that would allow for my to manipulate in production of application that is going to merge new HRMS application data with legacy HRMS application data.

Any tips, tricks, or good reading material?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of PeopleTools (8.52) has the ability to syndicate pretty much anything stored in the PeopleSoft system via the PeopleSoft Feed Publishing Framework.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E25741_01/psft/acrobat/pt852tfee-b1011.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it depends which version of PeopleTools you are on.

If you're reasonably current any component of PeopleSoft can be exposed using a Web Service.  This way you can add/update/retrieve any data that you like.  Also, if you're after a larger dump of data (which it sounds like you are) then you can expose a Query as a Web Service - so you could create a query to extract all open listings and make it available outside of PeopleSoft.